# Edit and Update values in dbgrid in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am new to delphi and I am creating a database for customers and I am able to populate their details in a dbgrid by Viewcustomers button. However I am trying to update their details by: selecting a row and change a value in a cell and updating the same by click of edit button.

I am able to do the same by selecting the row and fething the data in a seperate form. But i would like to do change the values in dbgrid itself and update. Could someone help? Updated with TDB navigator and dgEnabled property.

```
a)MySQL b)TDatasource c) In a form, to update a customer i did like:

procedure TForm5.editCustomersButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
begin
 for i:=0 to customersDataGrid.Columns.Count-1 do begin
  if customersDataGrid.Fields[i].FieldName='customerId' then 
        if customersDataGrid.Fields[i].FieldName='customerName' then customerNameValue.Text:=customersDataGrid.Fields[i].AsString;
        if customersDataGrid.Fields[i].FieldName='product' then productValue.Text:=customersDataGrid.Fields[i].AsString;
        if customersDataGrid.Fields[i].FieldName='city' then cityValue.Text:=customersDataGrid.Fields[i].AsString;
        if customersDataGrid.Fields[i].FieldName='country' then countryValue.Text:=customersDataGrid.Fields[i].AsString;
          begin
            try
              editCustomerQuery.Close;
              editCustomerQuery.Sql.Clear;
              editCustomerQuery.SQL.Add('UPDATE `employees_details`.`customers` SET `customerId`='''+customerIDValue1.Text+''', `customerName`='''+customerNameValue.Text+''', `product`='''+productValue.Text+''', `city`='''+cityValue.Text+''', `country`='''+countryValue.Text+''' WHERE `customerId`='+FloatToStr(customersDataGrid.Fields[i].AsFloat)+'');
              editCustomerQuery.Open;
              viewCustomerQuery.ApplyUpdates;
              viewCustomerQuery.Refresh;
              except on E : Exception do
            end;
          end;
        end;
        customerIDValue1.Text:='';
        customerNameValue.Text:='';
        productValue.Text:='';
        cityValue.Text:='';
        countryValue.Text:='';
        ShowMessage('Customer Changes have been updated in database');
        customersDataGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;
    end;
```

d) Just checking working of TDBedit in database demos it works, but i have created a new project with out any backend database still it doesn't allow me to edit.

Comment: a) What database back-end are you using?  b) Which dataset components are you using?  c) How are you doing the updates which you say work (on your "separate form"), by using db-aware controls or by generating your own Update statements in Sql.  Please add the code from your separate form to your q.  d)  Have you looked at any of the database demos that come with Delphi 7?  They all allow editing of the data.

Comment: Sorry, the answer to b) can't be "TDataSource".  A TDataSource is merely an intermediary between the component which actually retrieves and holds the db data, which is a specific descendant of TDataSet, such as TSqlQuery if you're using DBExpress, or TAdoQuery if you're using ADO.  What type is the DataSet connected to customersDataGrid.DataSource?  It's vital to know that ...

Comment: Btw, that code you added, "if customersDataGrid.Fields[i].FieldName='customerId' then 
        if customersDataGrid.Fields[i].FieldName='customerName'" cannot possibly work, because if the condition in the first "if ..." is true, i.e. that the field's name is 'customerid', it cannot pass the second "if .."  test,  because the **same** field's name cannot be 'customerName'.

Comment: What's the dataset you are using to provide records to TDBGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd post this as a new answer as it's become apparent that I'm not
answering the same question as I thought I was.  Below are extracts from
two D7 projects which provide in-place editing of a MySql table which
has an ID column and two 80-character-wide string columns.  Both are tested
and work fine.

The extracts are actually from the DFM files of the projects and show which
components you need, how to connect them up, and which properties you need to
set in the `Object Inspector` (the defaults the IDE gives to components dropped
on the form from the `Component Palette` are ok for the rest.

There is no code that needs adding to either of these projects:  All you need to do is to set the `Active` property of the dataset which is connected to `DataSource1` to `True`, i.e. `CDS1` for the DBExpress one and `ZQuery1` for the Zeos one.

Obviously, you would need to adapt the database name, field names, user name and
password to your database.

**DFMs**

Using DBExpress components (which come with D7)

```
      object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
        ConnectionName = 'OpenMySQL50Connection'
        DriverName = 'OpenMySQL50'
        GetDriverFunc = 'getSQLDriverMYSQL50'
        LibraryName = 'dbxopenmysql50.dll'
        LoginPrompt = False
        Params.Strings = (
          'DriverName=OpenMySQL50'
          'HostName=LocalHost'
          'Database=MATestDB'
          'User_Name=sa'
          'Password='
          'BlobSize=-1')
        VendorLib = 'libmysql.dll'
      end
      object SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery
        GetMetadata = True
        MaxBlobSize = -1
        Params = <>
        SQL.Strings = (
          'select * from MATable1')
        SQLConnection = SQLConnection1
        object SQLQuery1Table1ID: TIntegerField
          FieldName = 'Table1ID'
          Required = True
        end
        object SQLQuery1AName: TStringField
          FieldName = 'AName'
          Size = 80
        end
        object SQLQuery1AValue: TStringField
          FieldName = 'AValue'
          Size = 80
        end
      end
      object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
        DataSet = SQLQuery1
      end
      object CDS1: TClientDataSet
        Aggregates = <>
        Params = <>
        ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider1'
      end
      object DataSource1: TDataSource
        DataSet = CDS1
      end
      object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
        DataSource = DataSource1
      end
      object DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator
        DataSource = DataSource1
        Align = alBottom
        TabOrder = 1
      end
```

Using ZEOS components (available from SourecForge.Net)

```
      object ZConnection1: TZConnection
        ControlsCodePage = cGET_ACP
        AutoEncodeStrings = False
        Connected = True
        DesignConnection = True
        SQLHourGlass = True
        HostName = 'localhost'
        Port = 0
        Database = 'MATestDB'
        User = 'sa'
        Protocol = 'mysql'
        LibraryLocation = 'D:\aaad7\MySql\libmysql.dll'
      end
      object ZQuery1: TZQuery
        Connection = ZConnection1
        Active = True
        SQL.Strings = (
          'select * from matable1')
        Params = <>
      end
      object DataSource1: TDataSource
        DataSet = ZQuery1
      end
      object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
        DataSource = DataSource1
      end
      object DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator
        DataSource = DataSource1
      end
```

Comment: Thanks Martyn A for inputs, A friend of mine has helped me my making query's RequestLive property to true and it works.

Comment: Glad you found the solution.  As I've gone to the trouble of writing two answers, I think I'll roll them into one and add the "RequestLive" point; that way it may help future readers trying to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

It's best to add a TDBNavigator to your form and set its DataSource to the same one as the grid.  The point of doing this is that it gives you an easy way to save or cancel edits because of its buttons for those operations.

You should find that if you click twice in a cell in the grid, the first click focuses it and the second one puts it in edit mode.  Then, you can edit the cell value in-place.  If you want to avoid clicking the cell twice, set `dgAlwaysShowEditor` to `True`.

Btw, to enable in-place editing in the grid, the value `dgEditing` (under the grid's `Options` property in the `Object Inspector`) needs to be `True` and `dgRowSelect` needs to be `False`, as does the grid's `ReadOnly` property.

If you find that you can't edit a column value that you think ought to be editable, try the following:

- If you've got persistent TFields set up for the dataset, check the TField for that column in the `Object Inspector` to make sure that the field isn't marked read-only.
- Check that the dtataset doesn't have a read-only property that's set to True.
- Put a TDBedit on the form and connect it to one of the dataset's fileds.  Will that accept an edit.
- If none of those things work, you'll just have to do some debugging.  Inspect the grid's, fields' and datasets read-only properties at run-time using the debugger to make sure that none of them is True.  OR start a new project consisting of only one form, a dataset, dataset, dbgrid and a dbnavigator with properties set as I've described: Now, can you in-place edit in that?

As an alternative to using the DBNavigator's `Save` and `Cancel` buttons, you can simply call `DataSet.Post` and `DataSet.Cancel`.

Comment: I have tried using dgEditing True and I have attached a TDB Navigator to my grid, First click focus on it but second click doesn't allow me to edit the text in a cell.

Comment: In that case, the grid probably thinks that the dataset is read-only for somereason.  Check your component settings, in particular the grid's ReadOnly property.

Comment: I have just checked component settings, Datagrid's Readonly property= false.

Comment: Stiil stuck?  Did you try creating a new project as I suggested?

Comment: I have checked Readonly property= false everywhere in my existing project and i have also tried to create a new project by creating new form,dataset,dbgrid,dbnavigator and  TDBedit controls. Even in that i am unable to edit for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

Also make sure dgRowSelect is false. Editing and RowSelect are mutually exclusive (can't have both true at the same time).